# Ionic 2 push() direction: 'back' option not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, ionic2

[image]

**1** I have a product page that has a list of options.

**2** When clicked, this opens a new page with all the options listed.

**3** When I click an option, such as 'black', I want the page to go back to the product, but update the page with the new option selected. This looks like it worked, but I cannot scroll or select anything on the page.

[image]

(For some reason the product variation page is being shown over the new product page, which is why I can't select anything or scroll)

**4** And when I try to go back again to the product listings page, I get this mess.

**View**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="#option of productData">
    <ion-label>{{option.val}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio (click)="goToProduct($event, option.catalogId)" [checked]="option.val == selected"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

**Function**

```
goToProduct(event, catalogId) {
  this.nav.push(ProductPage, {
    catalogId: catalogId
  },{
    direction: 'back'
  });
}
```

I thought that I needed to remove the older product page, so I was doing:

```
goToProduct(event, catalogId) {
  this.nav.remove(1);
  this.nav.push(ProductPage, {
    catalogId: catalogId
  },{
    direction: 'back'
  });
}
```

And all sorts of variations like this, but nothing has worked.

I know that Ionic 2 is still in beta, is this a known issue? Or am I missing something? How can I select an option and make the updated page direction go backwards without destroying my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `insert()` instead of `push()` it goes backwards to the updated product just as desired, and completely removes the old product page. I didn't expect this behavior by reading the documentation, but I guess it's a nice and easy solution.

```
goToProduct(event, catalogId) {
  this.nav.insert(1, ProductPage, {
    catalogId: catalogId
  },{
    direction: 'back'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thankful for the above answer, it helped me a lot.
I was in the need to apply the **transition of my app pages** which I got accomplished with this but there was one issue as-

1. When ever I was boing back, It was ***overlapping*** some page at some point of time.
2. After doing some search, I got this issue resolved.

This is the code which I have as-

```
goBack() {
    {
      this.nav.insert(0,MyPage, {
        PId: this.parentId
      },{direction: 'back'});
    }

    {
      this.nav.pop();
    }
  }
```

We can also use `{direction: 'forward'}`  Depending upon our requirement.
I have just replace 1 with 0 parameter and working for me.

Have a nice Day!!!